# Systemd service not removing files

Tags: systemd

I am trying to have a service that removes all of the files within a directory every 60 seconds. I can tell that the service is restarting by checking the status for a few minutes and it is activating every minute

```
 Active: activating (auto-restart) since Sun 2020-09-20 10:46:06 UTC; 3s ago
Process: 479 ExecStart=/bin/rm -rf /data/* (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

This what I currently have as my service

```
[Unit]
Description=Cleans data directory

[Service]
User=root
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
ExecStart=rm -rf /data/*

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I did try having the Type=simple and I even got rid of the restart part and used a timer with the same name as the service but the files within /data do not get removed. The service should have permission since it has root level permissions but I cannot figure out why there would still be files within /data after several minutes.

Also, if I manually run the command `rm -rf /data/*` all of the files get removed.

Comment: AFAIK `*` will not be expanded in the context of an ExecStart command. - systemd service files are not shell scripts - or, as `man systemd.service` says, *"Note that shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell command lines are to be used, they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind."*

Answer (score 0):

Run the command via shell: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec rm -rf /data/*'`